# How do I get the new toolbar style in my pygtk app?

Tags: application-development, pygtk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the black header widget in some programs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67362/what-is-the-black-header-widget-in-some-programs)

I've noticed that I still have the old school gnome2 [GtkToolbar](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.2/GtkToolbar.html) style when I just run a simple glade/gtk application:

[image]

It should look like this:

[image]

This is Gtk 3.20, new widgets like GtkSwitch, GtkInfoBar, and GtkLockButton work fine. What do I have to do to get the new style toolbars?